# Add integers to jquery counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

This counter works great, with only one slight issue. I need it so that the numbers when selecting the checkboxes increase as such:

001, 002, 003, 010, 121, etc.

Reference: http://www.911dj.com/newsite/song-requests.htm

```
$(function () {
    $('#countcheck .counter').text(' ');
    var generallen = $("#song_list input[class='counted']:checked").lengthx0;
    if (generallen > 0) {
        $("#countcheck .counter").text('(' + generallen + ')');
    } else {
        $("#countcheck .counter").text('000');
    }
})
function updateCounter() {
    var len = $("#song_list input[class='counted']:checked").length;
    if (len > 0) {
        $("#countcheck .counter").text('' + len + '');
    } else {
        $("#countcheck .counter").text('000');
    }
}
$("#song_list input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
    updateCounter();
});
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your updateCounter function so that it adds zeros to the length based on the amount of checkboxes checked.

```
function updateCounter() {
    var len = $("#song_list input[class='counted']:checked").length,
        filler = '';
    if (len > 0) {
        if (len < 10) {
            filler = '00';
        } else if (len < 100 && len > 10) {
            filler = '0';
        }
        $("#countcheck .counter").text(filler + len);
    } else {
        $("#countcheck .counter").text('000');
    }
}
```